# What are the proper names of movie theatre quarters (rooms)

Tags: toponyms

How to correctly call lobby of a movie theatre where people are waiting?

How to correctly call the room where people watch the movie?

Comment: Around here the place where the film is shown is usually referred to as a "theater":  "Fantastic Beasts is showing in theater 3".  You buy popcorn in the lobby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On entering **front-of-house** in a British Isles cinema we may call it either the **lobby or foyer**. (can vary from palace to palace*) and in an up niche cinema with tables for drinks whilst watching or multiplex  we can have easily have two types of area, using lobby for main entrance and foyer for  bar.

We still often use **auditorium** for the theatre area where people watch films.

If your a film buff we find less and less **projection booths** as we switch to  digital boxes. Projectionists often called the projection room a **projection box** but that was from their perspective.
Ticket booths are rare, modern layout has desk and or counter with increasing ticket machines

- see comments below

Comment: From *place* to *place*, perhaps?

Comment: Haha, ah, erm ... one does not *drag* one’s self around. One *adjourns* to one’s abode. :P

Comment: They probably looked back at you and envied you actually living life. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Britain the lobby is called the 'foyer', pronounced as in French, but then we call a movie theatre a 'cinema', so what do we know? ;)